# python & scikit: How to get the parameter of fitted models from Gaussian mixture models fitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

After fitting the `gaussian mixture model`(X-Y dataset), how can I get the parameter of each distribution? e.g. `mean, std, and weights and angle` of each distribution?

I think I can find the code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_classifier.html#example-mixture-plot-gmm-classifier-py):

```
def make_ellipses(gmm, ax):
    for n, color in enumerate('rgb'):
        v, w = np.linalg.eigh(gmm._get_covars()[n][:2, :2])
        u = w[0] / np.linalg.norm(w[0])
        angle = np.arctan2(u[1], u[0])
        angle = 180 * angle / np.pi  # convert to degrees
        v *= 9
        ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(gmm.means_[n, :2], v[0], v[1],
                                  180 + angle, color=color)
        ell.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
        ell.set_alpha(0.5)
        ax.add_artist(ell)
```

After all, to plot the ellipse, you need to know the `mean,std,angle,weight`. But the code is really complex and I am wondering if there is any simpler method for it?

UPDATE: I find the attributes in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM.fit, now I'm working on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in [scikit's doc for GMM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM), once you have trained your model (call it `clf`), you can access its paremeters using `clf.means_`, `clf.covars_` and `clf.weights_`.

I'll add that you can check whether your model has been trained/has converged using the value of `clf.converged_`

Comment: Yes, that's what I've updated. It's very sad that the official code is not using these attributes.

Comment: Now days it's not `covars_` it's `covariances_` on more recent sklearn versions